# Removed WinXP association to U1, and can't get it to work anymore

Tags: ubuntu-one, windows

After testing the windows client for U1 sync, I decided to test the preferences' settings, and tried to remove the association for the WinXP station from which I was working.

Now I can start the client, but if I try to open the preferences' settings the application stops.

I tried to uninstall and reinstall, but that won't change the situation: apparently the old settings are kept the same even after a total reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there was a bug filled for this. What you have to do is look into your registry in the Windows machines. The the Current User Key ou will find a Canonical key that contains a encypted version of your Ubuntu One credentials (we use OAtuh for that).

What is happening is that the new installation is trying to reuse some keys that have been removed in the server side, so when it tries to do any work it goes bananas.

If you have problems with pop in #ubuntuone and look for mandel I'm the culprit of that code ;)

PS: I'm not usually here much, had you posted this on launchpad I would have answer it the same day, sorry...

Comment: Link to bug please.

Comment: I dont think there is a bug filled because the code is deprecated... in the next release that code is out.